# How to write a list of floats to csv in columns?

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv

i am searching everywhere for a method to write a list of floats into csv but must be in column format.

My code for writing csv as follow:

```
csvfile=open('Test.csv','w', newline='')
obj=csv.writer(csvfile)
obj.writerow(list_dis_B1_avg)
csvfile.close()
```

It turn out that the floats are written in rows.

I have a list of floats stored under "**list_dis_B1_avg**"

[image]

How can i just write it in column?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any csv module to do that:

```
with open("Test.csv", "w") as f:  # use with to close the file in any case 
    f.write("\n".join(list_dis_B1_avg))  # newline between the elements
```

More about the with keyword: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/

More about str.join(): https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join